# Buy a different app using in-app purchase in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app - say "**App1**" on the app store selling for $10. Now I start selling another app - say "**App2**" on the app store for the same price i.e $10.

I want the App2 subsidised for users who already have App1. i.e.

> if a user already owns **App1** then he can buy **App2** for just $5.

1. How can this be achieved? Is this even allowed by the iOS App store?
2. Can I sell App2 using in-app purchase from App1 ( and that too and a price different from that shown in the app store ) ?
3. Can I give a coupon in **App1** that I can redeem while purchasing **App2**?
4. Is this scenario possible --  I let the User buy **App2** for $10, but if he presents to me a token from **App1** (hence showing that he has in fact bought **App1**) I refund $5 back to his account.

Comment: I really doubt you will be allowed to do this since In-App purchases are for things that are consumed...in-app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly, one thing you could do is make two "lite" versions that have an in-app purchase to unlock "pro". You can then use some server infrastructure to merge the two. So App1 is $5, App2 in $5 and the IAP is $5.

Comment: This seems like the traditional approach. This doesn't directly cater to my problem. :(

Comment: Any idea on a coupon system? Can I give the user a $5 coupon in App1 that would be redeemed when he buys App2?

Comment: You can't generate vouchers on the app store

Comment: Can you point me to any resources about unlocking a "pro" version of an app as an in-app purchase? I'd love to allow a user to upgrade a free app in the app itself, rather than requiring they go to the app store manually.